# Default all Google Apps to English

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-workspace, google-docs, localization

I am currently travelling in Europe and every time I visit Google.com, or any Google Apps, like Sheets or Docs, it defaults to the region locale...

Currently, Google Sheets is showing me all menus in Italian, even though my browser and computer locale are set to English.

How can I change this back? I do not know Italian and cannot find the menu to change it back - further, their search proves unhelpful.

[image]

Why do these Google apps erroneously change language based on region, instead of the language that I *always* access the app using, nor use my default computer locale?

As far as I can tell, the outgoing request includes:

```
Accept-Language: en-US
```

However, I am still served an incorrect locale. Seems like an issue with Google itself.

> How can I force all Google apps to use English?

Comment: Why do they not respect the `Accept-Language` header? Is that not the purpose of it? Seems like it's an issue with Google not properly respecting the headers.

Comment: Google Search is a web application.  Comments removed.

Comment: Google is software and having a universal solution to do this would be helpful to some... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

- open this link **https://myaccount.google.com/language**
- change your language as desired
- if its set on English and doesn't display English at all, just set it on any different language and then set it back

**SELEZIONA (ita) = SELECT (eng)**

[image]